# find out if there is a route between two points in spatial database

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis, geospatial, spatial

I am beginner in  the matter of `spatial databases` I am using `MS SQL Server 2014` with database structure as follows:

```
Point {
  id int AI,
  point geometry,
  name text
}
Path{
  id int AI,
  path geometry,
}
```

column `point` is created as `(x,y)` and `path` as set of start point and end point as `linestring` `(x y, x y)`

I would like to check if there is connection through many `paths` from one `point` to another. Is there anyway to check it in `SQL`?
I can believe that I can do it at the server side or manually check all connections from first `point` etc. and in the end I will knew each combination (but I want to knew boolean value yes or no or the number of possible paths).

I can't find any good article nor book about spatial database and looking for a path function...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Geospatial STIntersects method. [Look at MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb933899.aspx)

```
DECLARE @g geometry;
DECLARE @h geometry;
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 2, 2 0, 4 2)', 0);
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 0);
SELECT @g.STIntersects(@h);
```

to use in a select statement:

```
Select geometryColumn.STIntersects(@g)
from Test
```

Comment: I do not quite understand it. Is it possible to use `STIntersects` with tables as I have mentioned it in the question?

Comment: @Mithrand1r apologies. just updated example and link for Geometry and included example from a select

Answer (score 0):

Sarin's answer is right but still not complete.

The following query pick point id 1 and checks if is intersect with any path:

```
SELECT Path.path.STIntersects(Point.point)
FROM Point CROSS JOIN dbo.Path
WHERE Point.id=1
```

I've tested the query with the same values as the ones from sarin's answer:

```
INSERT INTO Path (path)
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 2, 2 0, 4 2)', 0)),
       (geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 4 4)', 0))
GO
INSERT INTO Point (point, name)
VALUES (geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1 1)', 0), 'myPoint');
```

So the first path returns 0 (does not intersect with 1,1) and the second one returns 1.

Comment: is it possible having such `query` in a database where linestring is created from 2 points? for example I have 3 points `(1,1)` `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` and I have two edges `linestring(1 1, 1 2)` and `linestring (1 2, 1 3)` can I use `STIntersects` to find if I have a path between `(1,1)` and `(1,3)` ?

Comment: @Mithrand1r of course :) I've tried with 3 points for each path, but you can also do that with 2 at the same way.

Comment: Thank You mordack! I will check it in following hours and post here the result ! :)